# Email Alerts in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I am working with TFS 2010 and wanted to set up email alerts, here is my requirement. I have created a new TeamProject in one of the collections, customized the task template. Now following groups are having access to create tasks: Dev, QA, PM, and Support group.

Now I need to set an email alert in such a way that whoever creates the task, the email should go only to that person who has created it, in addition, it should send alert to the assigned person as well.

I tried using Power tools it did not help. How can I achieve this in TFS 2010?

Comment: (Not really a programming question, but definitely dev-related...)  What did you try in PowerTools?  This sounds like two separate alerts to me - one for creation, one for assigning.

Comment: i tried using "Any change in this project" the problem with this is if QA group create task mail is going to Dev and PM including QA and vice-verse... may be i am missing something here... can you guide me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Visual Studio

Go to Team -> Alert explorer ->  and Create new Alter Definition

Set Fields colum as "Assigned to"
Operator column "changes to" and in the value column put your name/email address.

Comment: Thanks for reply, the above expression will send email to assigned person, in addition what i need is that TFS should automatically send email to the person who has created the task saying task has been created.